# Laravel : merge an array inside map function

Tags: arrays, laravel, dictionary, merge

I'd like to make a new array with map function and merge it with another one.

for instance I have an array like below:

```
$arr1=['x' => 0 , 'y' => 0]
```

and an example query which is gonna make another array with its keys and then I'd like to merge them and back the results to the $query

```
$query->mapWithKeys( function ($item,$key) use ($arr1) {

  $arr2 = [$item-> a => $item-> b]; // for example it generates ['x' => 20 , 'y'=>30]

return collect($arr1)->merge ($arr2);// this returns ['x' => 0 , 'y' => 30]

});
```

I need the results of merge should be like this :

```
['x' => 20 , 'y' => 30]
```

Comment: You can use array_merge, `return array_merge($arr1, $arr2);`

Comment: @Donkarnash this won't work .we are using collection helper function like that .both have the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem with altering (merging) the query out of the map function as following :

```
$query->mapWithKeys( function ($item,$key)  {

  return 'data'=>[$item-> a => $item-> b]; // for example it generates ['x' => 20 , 'y'=>30]

});
```

and now we alter the query with using .each() as following:

```
  $query = $query->each(function ($item, $key) use ($arr1) {

          return  $item->data =  collect($arr1)->merge($item->data);
        });
```

If there would be a better solution kindly let me know guys